# ssh tunnel setup via a gateway, possible?

Tags: ssh, tunneling

local -> gateway ( only ssh port enabled ) -> remote

I can ssh to gateway then to remote, no problem.

Can I establish a ssh tunnel between local and remote via gataway?  I 'd like to access local:9980, which will forward to remote:9980 via gateway.
I'm worried about tunnel using port 22 on gateway will be a trouble for others' ssh use.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

Is your gateway an actual gateway/router? or is it a gateway/server?

If it's a gateway/router, then you can use port forwarding or NAT.  I'd give you instructions, but that depends on the OS/manufacturer.  Essentially, you have the gateway/router listen on port 22, and you forward to `destination:9980`, so long as **destination** is listening on 9980, this should work automatically.

If it's a gateway/server (assuming linux-based), then you can use an IPTABLES NAT rule, or a reverse ssh tunnel (which should be initialized from the destination end).

EXAMPLE IPTABLES NAT:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING --src 0/0 -p tcp --dport 22 -j REDIRECT --to-destination $destination_ip --to-ports 9980
```

This would take any incoming traffic from the any address for port 22 and forward it to your **$destination_ip** on port 9980 automatically.

EXAMPLE REVERSE SSH TUNNEL:

```
destination# ssh -R 9980:localhost:22 user@gateway
```

This sets up a listener on the gateway that maps anything going to `gateway:9980` to point to `destination:22`

For you, if you connect to your gateway like normal:

```
local# ssh user@gateway
```

You would then be able manually connect to the **destination** from your **gateway** as needed, instead of automatically

```
gateway# ssh user@localhost:9980
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you can do a SSH tunnel to `remote` through your `gateway`.
To do that:

```
ssh -L 9980:remote:9980 gateway
```

will bind your local 9980 to the remote 9980 port using ssh tunnel through gateway.